# Understanding a few of the preset marks

Tags: mark

When doing `:marks`, there are a few marks that show up that I'm not quite sure what they do, even after reading the entry in the help section. For example, the following marks seem a bit obscure (at least in my understanding) to me:

- `'0-9` (shows a bunch of files for me)
- `'"` (almost always shows the same thing as doing `gg`, is this always L1?)
- `'^` (how is this different than `'.` ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marks 0-9 are the last 10 files you were editing. See `:h viminfo-file-marks` (took me a while to find the correct help subject).

- `'"` : the cursor position when last exiting the current buffer (`:h '"`). Exiting here means closing the buffer (`:bd`) or exiting Vim while you edit a file. It does not mean leaving the buffer (like switching to another buffer). This mark is stored in the viminfo file (see `:h viminfo`). It can be used to restore the cursor position when you edit the file again (see `:h restore-cursor`).
- `'^` : the position where the cursor was the last time when Insert mode was
  stopped (`:h '^`)
- `'.` : the position where the last change was made (`:h '.`).

If you insert some text, `'^` and `'.` will point to the same location (nearly - `'.` is on the last inserted char, `'^` after the last inserted char except for end-of-line).

If you do some change without inserting (e.g. delete a line) `'.` will reflect that position, while `'^` is unchanged.

Comment: thanks for this. Could you please explain `the cursor position when last exiting the current buffer` a bit more ?

Comment: @David542 If you `:bd` a buffer and then `:e` that same file again, `'"` will take you to the line you were before you deleted it. If you have a viminfo file and save that mark there, that is typically used to restore the cursor to the last location whenever you open a file, so you're on the same context as when you last quit Vim on that file.

Comment: @David542 updated